# Is this legal to avoid set from creating actual copies of Comparator object

Tags: c++, templates, stl, set, functor

In such a code:

```
Comparator comp(3);

set<string, Comparator> s1(comp);
set<string, Comparator> s2(comp);
set<string, Comparator> s3(comp);
set<string, Comparator> s4(comp);
```

the actual instance of the Comparator (namely comp) is copied at each creation of a set object as the cpp reference states

> The container keeps an internal copy of alloc and comp, which are used
>   to allocate storage and to sort the elements throughout its lifetime.

So we were wondering if this is legal in C++

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i = 0;
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        ++i;
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    A a;
    std::set<int, A&> s1( {1, 2, 3}, a);
    std::set<int, A&> s2( {4, 5, 6}, a);
    std::cout << a.i;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _'So we were wondering if this is legal in C++'_ At least it [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/O85lFk), and does what's expected IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's not a valid argument at all in C++

Comment: My feeling says it is a fragile solution; comparators are typically expected to be stateless or to externalize their state (like e.g. an pimpl does); I am not sure what the standard says, i.e. if a set is required to store its copy of the comparator or to honor that it's a reference. Unfortunately, I lack the time at this moment to research it.

Comment: @phresnel But at least a good hint usually ;) ... Mentioning intended statelessness hit's the nail.

Comment: I feel pretty certain this isn't legal...  Doesn't the comparitor type have to be copiable at least?
[Edit: spec says it has to be swappable, are references swappable?]

Comment: @Mooing Duck I read that part as the compare has to be swappable only if you care to swap the container itself.

Comment: @MarkB: You're right, I overlooked the (quite obvious) context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unable to find wording in the standard forbidding using a reference type as the comparison function. Thus it seems that this would be legal. Note that some things, such as default constructing such a set, will be forbidden because your comparison type is not default constructable.

Finally note that the canonical C++ approach is to *not* do this, but to maintain the state externally. When you take that approach it's totally clear what you're doing and guaranteed to be safe:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int& i_;
    explicit A(int& state) : i_(state) { }
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        ++i_;
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main() {
    int i;
    std::set<int, A> s1( {1, 2, 3}, A(i));      
    std::set<int, A> s2( {4, 5, 6}, A(i));        
    std::cout << i << endl;
}
```